# Meaning of 日本に来られたらより理解できる

Tags: translation, comparative-constructions

I wrote:

> １４、１５歳だった時、僕は飛ぶことができる車を作ってみたくなったので、いろいろな自動車メーカーに興味を持った。フォルクスワーゲンとかHONDAとかビュイックとかBMWとか。「どこのメーカーのために飛べる車を作ればいいかな」と思って、僕の父に「好きな自動車メーカーは？」と聞いた。父の答えは「もちろん、TOYOTA。このメーカーの車はとても頑丈で長持ちするからね」。それで、僕はTOYOTAを選んだ。１ヶ月後、僕は科学の先生と僕の将来について話していた。
>
> 「TOYOTA！面白い！その自動車メーカーの本社は日本にありますね。じゃ、日本語を習ってみたらどうですか？」と先生が言った。それで、僕は日本語を習い始めた。
>
> アメリカがダメだから別の国に行きたいというわけではありません。日本語を習い始めたからです。日本語ではなくて、別の言語を習い始めていたら、たぶん、その言語の国に行きたくなる。(^-^)

And a user responded:

> 日本語が堪能ですね。驚きました。トヨタの車は確かに高品質だと思います。日本人の気質を表しているのかもしれません。**日本に来られたらより理解できると思います**。

I am totally stumped on the last sentence. The best guess I have is:

> 日本に来られたらより理解できると思います
>   Rather than coming to Japan, I think it would better if you could understand it.

What is your translation and why?

Comment: One general question. You want to say that, since teenage years, you wanted to build flying cars. Shouldn't your sentence then be: 車を作ってみたかったので and not 車を作ってみたくなったので
？

Comment: @RnBandCrunk I wanted to say that during my teenage years I 'became wanting' to build a flying car, as in, during that time I began to have the idea of building a flying car.

Comment: Holy crap, I didn't recognise it. Of course, みたい + なる　= みたくなる。
I confused my brain thinking it was the past form of みたくない (of course the past form of みたくない is みたくなかった and not みたくなった)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say

> If you were to come to Japan, you would be able to understand it better.

The より attaches to 理解できる not to the V-たら construction.

See:

[http://www.amazon.co.jp/より理解を深める-体液電解質異常と輸液-柴垣-有吾/dp/4498123123](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E7%90%86%E8%A7%A3%E3%82%92%E6%B7%B1%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B-%E4%BD%93%E6%B6%B2%E9%9B%BB%E8%A7%A3%E8%B3%AA%E7%95%B0%E5%B8%B8%E3%81%A8%E8%BC%B8%E6%B6%B2-%E6%9F%B4%E5%9E%A3-%E6%9C%89%E5%90%BE/dp/4498123123)

http://www.univcoop.or.jp/about/book/known.html

Comment: So basically, より in this case would mean 'more' or 'better'?

Comment: yes, pretty much.

Comment: @RichardWatson We say "good than" or "high than" under Japanese grammar so we have no comparative like "-er". But if you have to tell "better" or "higher" without "than", you could use several workaround, and one of those is adverb より "more, rather".